# load all css/js in single http request

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to know how to convert multiple CSS/JS requests into a single HTML request. I would appreciate any help with that. Thank you!

From

```
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="//eatfresh.com/skin/m/1465294353/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/styles.css">
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="//eatfresh.com/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/madisonisland.css">
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="//eatfresh.com/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="//eatfresh.com/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/eatfresh.css">
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="//eatfresh.com/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/image-hover.css">
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="//eatfresh.com/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

To

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//eatfresh.com/skin/m/1465294353/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/styles.css,/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/madisonisland.css,/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/bootstrap.min.css,/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/eatfresh.css,/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/image-hover.css,/skin/frontend/rwd/eatfresh/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: Look into bundling/minification. It needs to be done server side though.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done server side and is called concatenation. You need to use a task-runner like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (I prefer the former).

You cannot combine css and javascript into one file, you can only put all your css files into one css file and the same for javascript. However, you can do great things like minification with [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS), css [autoprefixing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer), [image minification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin), [javascript linting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jslint), and so much more.

See this [blog post](http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-task-runner-gulp) for a beginners guide to gulp and task runners in general.

### EDIT

I said you "need" to use a task runner, that is wrong. You don't *need* to use one but you *should*. These tasks that I mentioned can be done manually but a task runner allows you to run them all sequentially and with one command. It makes front-end development *much* easier.